# How to set DIrectory Upload File by our self

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I created an upload file. If I add target directory in target file name, my file doesn't upload. But I just set target file name without target directory, I'm success for uploading but my file in one directory with my controller. What should I do?

**My Code with target directory**

```
    $target_dir = "img/psychotest/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $target_file = $target_dir.$_POST['DocType'] . "_" . $_POST['email'] .".". $imageFileType;
```

Result : My file doesn't upload

**My Code wihout target directory**

```
    $target_dir = "img/psychotest/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $target_file = $_POST['DocType'] . "_" . $_POST['email'] .".". $imageFileType;
```

Result :  Success upload

Comment: do you have those two snippets the wrong way around?

Comment: No, my problem -->> I wanna upload file within directory what I want. But, my file doesnt upload if I add directory. @delboy1978uk

Comment: yes, but your post says 'my code without target directory', and it does have target directory! And vice versa!

Comment: I edit it @delboy1978uk

Comment: ok have you tried the stuff in my answer below?

Comment: SOLVED, I create new variabel to set a name in above move_uploaded_files function. And it works.. Thanks @delboy1978uk

Comment: did my answer help? if so could you mark it correct?

Comment: I removed SOLVED from the title, accepting an answer marks it as such if one did solve it. If not, post your own answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `realpath('img/psychotest/')` to determine the absolute path of the target dir.

If it returns false, the path is wrong and does not exist! Of course these are the issues you face when using relative links, so realpath is a great way to fix it!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

If it **does** return false, you can try echoing `getcwd()` to find out which directory PHP is actually sitting in at that point in time. Then tweak your path until `realpath` gives you a full absolute path for your target dir.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php